# This error keep on pop up: No view found for id 0x7f08003d

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, fragment, android-cardview

I am created a fragment and I want to insert it into a framelayout which is  inside the content of my cardview. Inside the fragment there is another reyclerView.

```
View view;
private List<DayViewItem> dayItemList = null;

public static Day_Fragment newInstance() {
    // Required empty public constructor
    Day_Fragment day_fragment = new Day_Fragment();
    return day_fragment;
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_day_, container, false);

    initializeDayItemList();

    //Create recyclerview
    RecyclerView dayRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.day_recycler_list);

    // Create the grid layout manager with 2 columns
    GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 1);

    // Set layout manager.
    dayRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);

    // Create recycler view data adapter with item list.
    DayViewDataAdapter dayDataAdapter = new DayViewDataAdapter(dayItemList);
    // set data adapter
    dayRecyclerView.setAdapter(dayDataAdapter);

    return view;
}

private void initializeDayItemList() {

    if (dayItemList == null)
    {
        dayItemList = new ArrayList<DayViewItem>();

        dayItemList.add(new DayViewItem("Blade Replacement","Normal", "Done"));
        dayItemList.add(new DayViewItem("Blade Replacement","Daily", "Done"));
        dayItemList.add(new DayViewItem("Device Change Setup Checklist","Normal", "Cancel"));
        dayItemList.add(new DayViewItem("Device Change Setup Checklist","Daily", "Cancel"));
    }
}
```

I insert the fragment in MainActivity

```
Fragment DayFragment = new Day_Fragment();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right)
            .replace(R.id.day_container, ((Day_Fragment) DayFragment).newInstance())
    .commit();
```

I having this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f08003d (com.example.nestedrecyclerview:id/day_container) for fragment Day_Fragment{2b9a2b0 #0 id=0x7f08003d}
```

Comment: Where is `day_container` exactly? That is, which layout is it in, and where is that layout being used?

Comment: day_container is in the RecyclerviewItem layout which is in a cardview. I am using recyclerview to generate my list of cardview. Inside my cardview i want to insert another fragment that is also a RecyclerView

Comment: `Fragment`s generally aren't used in `RecyclerView` items. It is possible, but it's cumbersome, and error-prone. Does the outer `RecyclerView` really need to be a `RecyclerView`? For example, it's relatively easy to use `Fragment`s with a `ViewPager`. Can you use that instead?

Comment: I am doing this way because I wanted to create a nested recyclerview with cardview

Comment: Right, but your desired setup is not going to be as straightforward as using a `Fragment` directly in an `Activity`. I'm trying to find an easier solution for you. Can you use a `ViewPager` instead? Also, I see that your `dayItemList` only has four items in it. Is it only ever going to have four items? If so, then you don't really need a `RecyclerView`, and you wouldn't need the `Fragment` to manage it. You could just make a regular `View` to put in the `Activity`'s `RecyclerView` with those four items.

Comment: no the 4 items is just doing testing, item data will come from the database, thus i need recyclerview to display it. I will try to do it in viewpager

Answer (score 0):

The `R.id.day_container` is not found, and this can be due to a variety of things. For instance, loading different resources based on language or device resolution, and this id not being found in the resource that has been loaded, or accessing an R file that does not contain this resource.

- Could you double-check that the resource you are loading contains this particular ID? (`day_container`)
- Could you use the full qualified name on the R resource? (`your.package.R.id.day_container`)

Comment: `<FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/day_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>` I declare this id for my framelayout

Comment: Is this FrameLayout being loaded in your current Activity? Because the error says it cannot find it ```day_container```

Comment: The frame layout is in my RecyclerViewItem xml file which is inside a cardview

Comment: You are trying to replace a Fragment in a Frame that is supposed to be loaded in the Activity. You should not use a Fragment as a RecyclerView item.

Answer (score -1):

Please use

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```

to bind views (i.e., `findViewById`).

`onCreateView()` is used to inflate layout but not to bind views (i.e., `findViewById`)

Comment: agree, but the code need some more fix so I posted, anything wrong in it??